# Why can't I specify regex_constants in assign?

Tags: c++, regex, string, visual-studio-2015, case-insensitive

I am using std::regex with VS2015/VS2017 on Windows. I am trying to set up a general routine that will do a search search to perform the 8 functions as requested by the user:

1. Begins with
2. Does not begin with
3. Ends with
4. Does not end with
5. Contains string
6. Does not contain string
7. Contains any of the characters in supplied string
8. Does not contain any of the characters in supplied string.

The routine is passed the type above, the associated string, the string to search, a boolean variable to state if the search is case sensitive/insensitive and another boolean variable on whether to restrict the search for whole words only (types 1-6 only). I modify the supplied find string if "whole words only" is specified.

e.g.

```
void Search(std::wstring sRegex, std::wstring wsString, bool bCaseSensitive, bool bWholeWordsOnly);
```

However, I can't get basic case insensitivity to work as I expected.

This works:

```
std::wregex reg;
std::wsmatch m;

if (bCaseSensitive) {
  reg.assign(sRegex.c_str(), std::regex::ECMAScript);
} else {
  reg.assign(sRegex.c_str(), std::regex::ECMAScript | std::regex::icase);
}

std::regex_search(wsString, m, reg) .....
```

but this doesn't (icase ignored and worse):

```
std::wregex reg;
std::wsmatch m;

reg.assign(sRegex.c_str(), std::regex::ECMAScript |
                (bCaseSensitive ? 0 : std::regex::icase));

std::regex_search(wsString, m, reg) .....
```

Can anyone explain this please?

PS. I haven't yet coded more than type 1 yet as I want to fix this first before continuing. Any suggestions for the regex string for the other types with & without "whole word only" (where appropriate) would be gratefully received.

Comment: What happens if you use `reg.assign(sRegex.c_str(), (bCaseSensitive ? std::regex::ECMAScript : std::regex::ECMAScript | std::regex::icase));` instead?

Comment: Also, `std::regex::ECMAScript` is on be default.

Comment: Thank you.This worked:reg.assign(sRegex.c_str(), (bCaseSensitive ? std::regex::ECMAScript : std::regex::ECMAScript | std::regex::icase));